# Does deleting an object in c++ also delete other objects referenced by a pointer contained in the object

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I've been working a lot with classes and pointers recently and came across the following scenario:

I have an object of the DataBase class, which contains a std::vector of pointers to objects of the DataSet class, which contains a vector of floats.
Now the question is:
If I wish to delete all of these Datasets with their stored floats, is it enough to simply delete the object of the DataBase class or do I first need to delete all of the referenced DataSets and then Delete the DataBase object?

The Code for both classes:

```
class Dataset
{
public:
    Dataset();
    ~Dataset();
    std::vector<float*>* InputValues = new std::vector<float*>;
    std::vector<float*>* ExpectedValues = new std::vector<float*>;
};

class DataBase 
{
public:
DataBase();
    ~DataBase();
    int AddedDataSets = 0;
    std::vector<Dataset*>* DataSets = new std::vector<Dataset*>;
};
```

These vectos will be filled by other functions and by the end, I would like to delete them again using:

delete "name of the DataBase object";

Comment: It depends on what the destructor of the `DataBase` class does.

Comment: No, this is one reason raw pointers and `new` are to be avoided. You don't even need and dynamic objects here, just remove all the pointers and `new` from your code and it will work. `std::vector<float*>* InputValues` should just be `std::vector<float> InputValues;`. This code looks like it is inspired by Java or C#. `new` is not nearly as useful in C++ as it is in those languages, C++ encourages value semantics. In practice, in modern C++, there is almost no reason to use `new` or `delete`.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. To add to @FrançoisAndrieux's point, `std::vector` contains a default template parameter for its allocator, which will automatically handle memory allocation and deletion. This means that even if you use a non-pointer `std::vector`, your memory is still being dynamically allocated on the heap as long as you don't change the vector's allocator.

Comment: Unelated: if you need to have a destructor you probably also need special member functions to correctly handle copying and moving class instances. Se [the Rule of Three/Five/Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for details.

Comment: Deleting the object should be enough. If it isn't, it is because you designed the object wrong. It should clean itself up. If it doesn't, it's broken.

Comment: In all your uses cases above there is no need to use pointers or the `new` operation. Make them normal objects and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Use `Foo*` for non-owning pointers.  Use `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` for owning pointers.  *Voila!*  Problem solved.  And never use `new` or `delete` again.

Answer (score 2):

No. Subobjects like base classes and ordinary members will be deleted., but objects *pointed to* will not be.

That changes, of course, if you hold those addresses in smart pointers; that is, in fact, the whole point of them: The destructor of a smart pointer deletes the pointee if the conditions are right.

If you use ordinary pointers you must check the conditions and possibly delete the pointees yourself. Classes like `std::vector` do that: They contain a pointer to dynamically allocated memory and free that, after calling the destructor on each element. It is a worthwhile exercise to implement one. It is also clear why the vector cannot delete objects the pointers in its elements point to: It is not clear at all that that memory was dynamically allocated. You could push addresses of global variables which would crash the program if passed to `delete`. It is also possible that the addresses are stored somewhere else as well, where another attempt to delete them will be undertaken. These considerations who bears responsibility and has authority to delete objects concern what is called *ownership.*

Note that typically the pointers, respectively the pointees, must also be taken care of when such objects are assigned or copied. The default copy operation is to copy the address; if the destructor later deletes the object at that address it would be a disaster if two independent objects of your class pointed to the same address.

Comment: Okay, that already helps a lot.
If I understood correctly:
If I want to delete everything manually, I need to delete the individual pointee floats in a for loop, then call the destructor on the vector, call the destructor on the object holding the vector and so on and so forth?
Alternatively I'd have to replace the pointers with smart pointers, that automtically delte the pointees if I delete the pointer itself, correct? ^^

Comment: @FLOROID Yes exactly. But the manual way is cumbersome.  As Francois said, the vectors should be regular objects, not pointers; that will call at least the *vector* destructor automatically when your class object is destroyed. Proceed  to level 2 ;-): The vector calls the destructors of its elements, but they don't do anything for ordinary pointers. If you use **smart pointers** as elements instead, their destructor will do the right thing (e.g. for unique_ptr simply call delete on the contained raw address). And smart pointers also take care of (or prevent) copying and assigning.